# Comparing multiple arrays against multiple arrays (in ruby or python)

Tags: python, arrays, ruby, compare, multiplication

I have 39208 arrays. Labelled `a1, a2, a3, a4,... a39208`.
I want to be able to compare each array against all the other arrays.

```
(a1-a2).empty?; (a1-a3).empty?; (a2-a3).empty?;... (a4-a39208).empty?
```

I'm not sure how to code an array name change in my code. For example if I had a loop:

```
  b = 0
     loop do
       b +=1
       m = ["a1" + b.to_s]
       w = m
       k = (m - a1).empty?
     puts k
   if b == 39208
  break
  end
 end
```

NOT ACTUAL CODE: Just trying to convey an idea. Where `m` should change to `a2, a3, a4, a5` As the loop goes along. I know it would just append a # on the end and I would end up with `a11, a12, a13`

So with out having to write `(a1-a2).empty?; (a1-a3).empty?; (a2-a3).empty?;... (a4-a39208).empty?` until the end of time. How do I have it that the code `(a1-a2).empty?` changes into `-a3, -a4, -a5,... -a390208`. => `(a1-a39028).empty?`

What I'm trying to do is input another array into the code changing which array is facing off against the other.

Perhaps there are any other ways of going about this. I can change the arrays into lists, or strings.

EDIT: 
Each array contains 30 numbers, there are 39208 arrays. I'm looking to find the all the arrays that are the same and list each duplicate array.

Comment: What does `(a1-a2).empty?` mean?

Comment: What's in the arrays? numbers, strings etc?

Comment: are `a1`, `a2` the name of the variables?

Comment: What is the source of the "labeled" arrays? Would make more sense to store them in a single container, like a list, then you wouldn't have to deal with so many of them and they could be iterated over without have to specify each name (in either language).

Comment: a1, a2 is the name for the array.

Comment: What @martineau's asking is how you're getting the data into your interpreter to begin with. Do you have a script where you're manually setting `a1 = [...]`, `a2=[...]`, and so on? _How_ is the data being loaded?

Comment: The data is already set. I was given the data in a spread sheet.

Comment: Sure, but then how are you loading that spreadsheet into the interpreter? Are you using the [Ruby CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) lib? Are you just copy-pasting it? Can you share the code where you load the data from the spreadsheet?

Comment: I just copy and pasted into sublime from excel. Glyoko thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out the [csv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-All+at+Once) lib. You can use it to programmatically read your data in. That way you won't have to deal with a million variables. Regarding my below answer, `all_arrays = [a1, a2, a3, ... a39208]` just becomes `all_arrays = CSV.read("path/to/your/file.csv")`. Excel should have an option to export an .xls file to a .csv file somewhere.

Comment: Copy pasting from excel just sucks. Don't do that, read CSV file programmatically like Glyoko suggests.

Answer (score 6):

So first off, the bigger problem here is that you're dealing with 39208 variables. There is almost certainly a better way to work with your data without needing to deal with that many variables. I don't know how you're getting this data into your code, but you should start by putting all these variables into a single array so you don't have to deal with so many variables, e.g.

```
all_arrays = [a1, a2, a3, ... a39208]
```

After that, you can use [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) to iterate over all pairs in `all_arrays`:

```
all_arrays.combination(2).map do |arr1, arr2|
  (arr1 - arr2).empty?
end
```

`all_arrays.combination(2)` will give you *all pairs* of elements in `all_arrays`.

---

Looking at it again, it should be pointed out that you may also want to compare these elements in reverse. For some arrays, `(a1 - a2).empty?` might be true, but `(a2 - a1).empty?` might be false. e.g.

```
a1 = [1,2,3]
a2 = [1,2,3,4]

(a1 - a2).empty?
# => ([1,2,3] - [1,2,3,4]).empty?
# => ([]).empty?
# => true

(a2 - a1).empty?
# => ([1,2,3,4] - [1,2,3]).empty?
# => ([4]).empty?
# => false
```

If this matters for your use case, just use [Array#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) instead:

```
all_arrays.permutation(2).map do |arr1, arr2| ...
```